# delegate or reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates

I have a class with a method in which a string will be passed. That method will do some things to that string and it then passes the string to a certain object which can do other things with the string.

So it basically looks like this:

```
class Main
{
     public Main()
     {
         strClass str = new strClass(this);
     }

     public function handler ( )
     {
         console.log("No string is passed yet, but this method is called from receiveData()");
     }
}

class strClass
{
    object handler;
    public strClass ( handler )
    {
        // save the object
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    public receiveData ( string str )
    {
        // This method does some stuff with the string
        // And it then passes it on to the supplied object (handler) which will do
        // the rest of the processing

        // I'm calling the "handler" method in the object which got passed in the 
        // constructor
        Type thisType = this.handler.GetType();
        MethodInfo theMethod = thisType.GetMethod("handler");
        theMethod.Invoke(this.handler, null);
   }
}
```

Now this code works good, with the reflection stuff. But i was wondering, shouldn't this be possible (and maybe even better?) with delegates?? If so, how can i implement this by using a delegate instead?

Comment: the compiler errors make it a little hard to make sure we're answering the same question here... it would be good if it ran (since it "works good")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A delegate is a better option here.

```
class Main
{

     public Main()
     {
         StrClass str = new StrClass(this.Handler);
     }

     public void Handler ( )
     {
         //called from recieve data
     }
}

class StrClass
{
    readonly Action _handler;
    public StrClass ( Action callback)
    {
        // save the object
        this._handler = callback;
    }

    public void receiveData( string str )
    {
        this._handler();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great and seems to be a much better solution then what i had.

Answer (score 5):

Couldn't you use interfaces instead:

```
 interface IStringHandler {
     void HandleString(string s);
 }


 class strClass 
 {
      IStringHandler handler = null;

      public strClass(IStringHandler handler)
      {
          this.handler = handler;
      }

      public void ReceiveData(string s)
      {
          handler.HandleString(s);
      }
 }


 class Main : IStringHandler
 {
      // Your code
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with an `Action` like this:

```
class Main 
{
    public Main()      
    {
        strClass str = new strClass(newString => 
        {
             console.log("This string I got back: " + newString);      
        });
    } 
 }  
 class strClass 
 {     
    Action<string> callback;
    public strClass (Action<string> callback) 
    { 
        // save the action
        this.callback = callback;     
    }
    public receiveData ( string str )     
    {
        // Do something with the string
        callback(str);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even nicer than using delegates whould be using the 
[Chain of Responsibility design pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternChain.aspx), which does exactly what you need :).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you *must* call an unknown method by name, use `dynamic` - it is heavily optimised for this (although still not a great idea):

```
((dynamic)handler).handler(); // but please don't use this! see below
```

However, I would instead look at either an `Action<string>` (or maybe `Func<string,string>`), or an interface with a known method on it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to change how  your `StrClass` object react to data begin received. Sounds like events to me.

something like this, where you have handling methods both in the `Main` and in a generic `HandlerObject`:

```
class StrClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = null;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
    }

    private string receivedString;
    public string ReceivedString
    {
        get;
        set
        {
            string oldStr = receivedString;
            receivedString = value;
            PropertyChanged(receivedString, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ReceivedString"));
        }
    }

    public void receiveData(string str)
    {
        //event fires here
        ReceivedString = str;
    }
}

class HandlerObject
{
    public void HandlerMethod1(string s)
    {
        //magic
    }

    public void HandlerMethod2(string s)
    {
        //different kind of magic
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void HandlerMethod3(string s)
    {
        //another kind of magic!
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StrClass class1 = new StrClass();
        StrClass class2 = new StrClass();
        StrClass class3 = new StrClass();

        HandlerObject handler = new HandlerObject();

        class1.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => { handler.HandlerMethod1(s.ToString()); };
        class2.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => { handler.HandlerMethod2(s.ToString()); };
        class3.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => { HandlerMethod3(s.ToString()); };
    }
}
```